# visual studio mac error on dotnet bundle

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I have a project in aspnetcore running on my mac with vscode seamless.
but when I try to open in visual studio for mac, I get the following error: Can´t execute bundle. error 127. 
in my csproj I have this target

```
<Target BeforeTargets="Build" Name="Bundle">
    <Exec Command="dotnet bundle" />
</Target>
```

if I open in visual studio for win, works.
if I remove this target, works.
can anyone knows whats happen ?

Comment: Does it work if you do an additional `dotnet restore` on the command line?

Comment: in command line works. but on visual studio for mac, dont works.